# How to tune hyper-parameters with validation data

Tags: validation, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm training a neural network machine learning model and am a little bit confused about how to tune hyper-parameters.

I see the training process as follows:

- build neural network with some hyper parameters (e.g. number of neurons in hidden layer)
- update parameters using training data
- use validation data to assess if model is not over-fitting and is improving
- use test data to assess performance

I've been told that validation data is also used to tune hyper-parameters. I don't understand how to do this since you use the validation data **after** you've built the model and trained it. I can't change a hyper-parameter because the model is already built.

Assuming I have 4 hyper-parameters which specify the architecture of a neural network. Am I supposed to go through the whole training, validation process for every hyper-parameter combination (4^4 combinations)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically yes ,you have to go through the whole process. Cross validation and model/parameter selection is done that way, you train multiple times(different parameters), evaluate  the resulting models(via cost,loss, accuracy or the appropriate metric) and  you select the parameters which gave your best results.

For example if you where training a regression model , you could train 10 different polynomial models ,and use validation data to select the better one, same in your case but you play with different network architectures.

Comment: Besides tuning, you can use the validation set for early stopping in training phase as in for every iteration compute not only train loss but also validation loss. then choose the parameter settings that produced the best validation loss as final model for test.